# Dynamically-added elements not wrapping

Tags: jquery, css, dhtml

I need to dynamically add elements to a page, but unfortunately when I do it using the jquery .append() method, the elements seem to act differently from other elements already on the page, despite the same CSS.

I created an [example page](http://gregmaclellan.com/temp/testwrap.html) that reproduces the problem.

on the top is a list (`ul` with a bunch of `li`'s ) with statically defined items. Below the hr is a `ul` set up the same way, but the `li`s are added dynamically (one every 600ms). The resulting HTML looks identical to me (except for the id), but clearly the results are different: 
 * The spacing on the `li`'s is shorter
 * more seriously, they don't wrap to the width of the browser: they simply cause a horizontal scroll to be added.

Can anyone explain why the results are different?

Ultimately, I want the newly-added elements to wrap to the size of their container. Seems to me like this CSS should work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding a new line after each `<li>` fixes it.

```
  function addRandom() {
        $('#cloud2').append('<li><a href="#">test</a></li>\r\n');
  }
```

Since your li tags are styled as inline elements, the white-space matters.

EDIT: adding a space works too:

```
  function addRandom() {
        $('#cloud2').append('<li><a href="#">test</a></li> ');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had fix it for you its now warping , just give it your prefered width

```
 <html> 
<head> 
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(addRandom,600);
  });

  var cnt = 0;
  function addRandom() {
        $('#cloud2').append('<li><a href="#">test</a></li>');
  }
  </script> 
  <style type="text/css"> 

div#container{
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color :#fff;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
        -moz-border-radius:5px;
    clear:both;
}
.list {
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    float:left
  }
  .cloud{
    padding:0;margin:0;
   }
  .cloud li {
        display:inline;
        margin-right:15px;
        list-style:none outside none;
        background:black;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    margin:3px;
        border-radius:5px;

  }
 .cloud li a{
    color:white;
    font-decoration:none;
  }
p{
clear:both;
}
 </style> 
</head> 
<body> 
 <div id="container">
<ul class="cloud"  id="cloud1"> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li> 
  </ul>
<p> <hr/>  </p>
<ul class="cloud" id="cloud2"> 
</ul> 
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```